# How does a switch knows where to send a packet before the MAC address of the destination is learnt?

Tags: networking, mac, switch

I am starting my journey on Computer Networks and currently learning about how switches work. Switches learn and store a MAC address once the device with the MAC address interacts with it. Given 2 devices (A and B) and 1 switch (S) where both devices are connected, if A is trying to send a message to B before B has already interacted with S, how does S know where to send the package?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't. It "floods" any packet to an unknown unicast MAC address (that is, it sends it to all ports except the one it came in on) as if it was a multicast or broadcast until it learns which port that MAC address lives on.

Comment: In that case, it expects a response from the adequate one I guess, no? And if there is no answer it decides that there is no system connected with that address?

Comment: @pdaranda661 I'm pretty sure the switch doesn't expect anything. IEEE 802.1D, which defines bridging/switching, was created way back when it would have been cost prohibitive for a switch to have to keep track of whether a flooded packet ever got a response. So switches will just keep flooding any packets to a unicast MAC address that never responds. However, this situation is highly unlikely to occur or persist for long in the real world. You'd have to have a host with a static ARP mapping for a host that's down, and be doing something unidirectional like…UDP syslog or something.